# Setting headers for Gzip response

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, gzip, response-headers

I'm using spring boot app. I have pre compress my gzip resources and sets appropriate headers for it but browser is not de-compressing it.So i need help. My resource name is bundle.js.gz.

**Request Header**

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch 
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6 
Cache-Control:no-cache 
Connection:keep-alive 
Cookie:NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY=%22en%22; 
Host:127.0.0.1:8080 
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8080/ 
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36

**Response Header**

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:gzip 
Content-Length:35255 
Content-Type:application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 17 Nov 2015 06:05:01 GMT 
Expires:0 
Last-Modified:Mon, 16 Nov 2015 07:42:30 GMT 
Pragma:no-cache 
 
Server:Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224) 
X-Application-Context:application:dev:8080 
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff 
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

I tried using contant-type : application/x-gzip and also using bundle.js instead of bundle.js.gz but all in vein.
So if anyone points any wrong header or direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: how does it show up: garbled, blank, or error?

Comment: it shows up as garbled.

Comment: i didn't know we could do gzip ahead of time like that. maybe we can't... if it shows up, then you are likely seeing the bytes of the zip file served as text without http gzip encoding. you might try a basic deflate in node, and then pipe the results to a file; a zip file!=gzip response; there's file name info et al, so it depends on how you make your compressed file, but if you can send the output from that node-made deflated binary file bit-for-bit, it should work.

Comment: i'm using gulp-gzip plugin to gzip file. I didn't want to compress on fly. because it would more efficient if we pre-compress file rather then compressing when someone request a file.

Comment: at browser, file contant is like this ��}kw�F��g�W Z���iJ���])ʬb)�f�ZKN�^��D@"���e�G��vU��_Hɖ�

Comment: @dandavis thanks for you help. I found the error. actually Server was also compressing the file, so the file is double gzip compressed and browser was only decoding it one time, that why the file content was garbled. so i remove the server compression and everything is now working well. :)